# nginx and jQuery file upload tool. Delete method

Tags: wordpress, nginx, centos

I have recently configured a wordpress site using a VPS setup with LEMP. I'm new to nginx so I'm using an nginx config I found [here](https://gist.github.com/878505).

Anyways, I'm using the [jQuery file upload tool](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) and I have it setup to where it uploads the files (images in this case) to a couple directories (php/file and php/crop) on upload.

When using the Delete button, The delete function is passed the URL `(example.com/server/php?file=image.jpg)` hitting the `index.php` which takes the delete request and deletes the images in the directories associated.

However, when I enable `'dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;'` in nginx, the delete request deletes the directory.

How do I make it where it hits `index.php` so that I can let it delete the files in the proper directories?

Comment: Can u paste your nginx config here? Its hard to debug like this.